# Verb for 'luck'

Tags: single-word-requests

If I got good grades with little study and preparation and no innately superior intellect, I would want to say that "I *lucked* through my exams".

However *luck* is not a verb. What can I say instead?

Edit:

This post has surprisingly spawned an interesting discussion about whether 'luck' is a verb or not? If it's not strictly a verb - but the context in which it is being passed off as a verb is clear and flows harmoniously with the rest of the sentence -  whether that legitimised its use?
Does anyone have any resources for this kind of topic?

Comment: Actually, you commonly hear Americans say "I lucked out" when something unexpectedly works in their favor, maybe it can be a verb in certain cases?  You can also say "I got lucky".

Comment: "I lucked through my exams" would be a perfectly normal thing to hear from an American student and nobody would misunderstand it IMO (US South here). It's non-standard usage, yes, but verbing nouns is a normal part of modern English and there's no reason to avoid it in everyday language.

Comment: In addition to being a noun, "luck" is a verb, found in most any dictionary as such.

Comment: @DarrenRinger _lucked_ maybe, but I've never heard of _luck_ as a verb.

Comment: do [phrasal verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb) satisfy the "single-word-request" tag? (Is that a meta question?)

Comment: In contrast to @trentcl, Upper Midwest US here and I don't think I've ever heard anyone say “lucked through.” It's immediately understandable, but definitely sounds weird.

Comment: "I lucked through my exams, but saw nothing" :)

Comment: @JEL The phrasal verb 'luck out' is a verb, but 'luck' without 'out' is definitely -not- a verb. That is, why close the question? Seeing it in the dictionary won't answer the OPs question.

Comment: Regarding the question about the use of "luck" as a verb (as opposed to "lucked") what about *"He always seems to **luck** into success, while others like myself work hard to barely surpass mediocrity?"* It sounds quite natural to me.

Comment: @Mitch, I'm not invested in the close vote, so I retracted it; it was more for lack of displayed research than inaccuracy, but I felt using the specific close reason might be more likely to prompt the research. As for 'luck' being "definitely -not- a verb", that's just plain wrong, as can be demonstrated with dictionaries, rather than your or others' personal experience or the lack of it. The verb is *colloquial*, originally US (but now has spread).

Comment: @JEL 'I lucked through the exam' = I (lucked) (through the exam) is not an English pattern. 'I lucked out on the exam' = I (lucked out) (on the exam) is. All I'm saying is that the question is about the first pattern. that is, that 'luck' by itself is definitely not a verb. You might still disagree but if so then we disagree about the parsing of and POS in the first sentence.

Comment: @Mitch, it's not that *we* disagree. The use here (attested from 1922 in *OED*) would be in a reflexive construction, probably: "I lucked my way through the exams." Plain old 'lucked' (sense attested from 1929 in *OED*) would do as well: "I lucked the exams." Either way, the issue is not parsing or POS, but observed use cases.

Comment: @JEL I find 'I lucked the exams' to be awful (and meaningless). "I licked my way through the exams" sounds like a new usage or new slang
, but is understandable to me.

Comment: @Mitch We do agree that it's awful. As the great Nero Wolfe once remarked (well, with reference to a different verb), we don't use 'luck' as a verb in my house. It has seen such use since 1438, and *OED* observes (about the similar sense 4, probably the sponsor of senses 5a and b, which I noted in my previous comment) "apparently re-formed in the 20th century". The use as a verb is etymologically justifiable, though, due to influence from Middle Dutch *lukken*, etc.

Comment: Just luck in the dictionary... ;-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I fluked my exams.**

> **fluke**
> VERB [WITH OBJECT] Achieve (something) by luck rather than skill.
>
> ‘I played very loose in contrast to the rest of the night's play and
> got ahead quite quickly thanks to fluking four of a kind early on.’
> https://www.lexico.com/definition/fluke

---

** Not to be confused with "flunk"!

Comment: I knew that word - used it all the time so how could I possibly not have been able to retrieve it? Is something wrong with me!

Comment: Better than my answer I think, though in the US I can’t recall ever having heard it used as a verb. Very interesting.

Comment: In the US many people would hear that as "flunked".

Comment: I've only heard fluke as a noun.  "How did you pass your exam?" "I don't know, I guess it was a fluke."  Not saying it's wrong, but you might get some weird looks.

Comment: I like this idea, but I would say "I fluked *through* my exams". "I fluked my exams" would raise an eyebrow for me (although I definitely wouldn't confuse it with "flunked", at least when spoken aloud...) but "fluke through", by analogy with "get through" suggests that you passed, but only by coincidence.

Comment: Fascinating. I had never encountered this word as a verb until today. I see from the lexico site, however, that this is a UK definition. If you switch to "US Dictionary" the verb form disappears. This seems to be one of those things you would say differently depending on your audience.

Comment: @DavidK but English is flexible enough that anybody who understands what the noun 'fluke' means would also understand what 'I fluked...' means

Comment: @TKoL I'm not entirely sure they would. At least in the U.S., a "fluke" isn't generally understood to be *good* luck. At the very least, I suspect it would take a few moments extra to parse.

Comment: @DavidK In my dialect at least, a fluke is generally considered good luck. Or a multimeter. (bad engineer joke, sorry!)

Comment: @Hearth I don't doubt you. Also, the preponderance of dictionaries seem to be against my interpretation (that it could be good luck or bad luck). In any case I found this answer to be useful and voted accordingly, hope we agree on that at least.

Answer (score 42):

Maybe you could use "lucked out" meaning

> to be very lucky

[[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/luck-out)]

It's considered a "phrasal verb with *luck* verb".

Might work for you.

Comment: This is what I would use. A variation is "luck up," which parallels "f*** up" and refers to getting lucky in spite of a blunder.

Comment: In American English, the standard phrasal verb is _luck out_, which is intransitive. Typical usage: _I lucked out and got an A- on that paper_.

Comment: In the 80's this was a common phrase. luck-out or lucked-out for "get lucky" or "was lucky". You actually couldn't say "got lucky" since lucky meant sexual activity

Comment: @OwenReynolds Just because getting lucky means getting sex doesn't mean lucky means sex.

Comment: Native AmE speaker here - wouldn't "lucked out" typically mean a difficult situation was avoided entirely? I think I might understand this with some more context, but if I ask you how you did on the exam and you tell me you "lucked out," my first interpretation is that you didn't have to take the exam. Of course, telling me the grade you got would clear it up.

Comment: Native UkE speaker here: I don't know where the publishers of the Cambridge English Dictionary are based, but "luck" as a verb is uncommon over here. Fluke as a verb is also fairly uncommon, but probably better accepted.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd Cambridge English Dictionary has been published by Cambridge University Press, based in the UK, since 1995. However, the online version does have both UK and US versions. William has posted a link to a definition on the US version.

Comment: I would say "I lucked out on my exams" to mean "I successfully passed my exams by guessing correct answers despite not being well prepared."

Comment: @GeoffAtkins This always reminds me of one of Arthur C. Clarke's little jokes, about universities in Cambridge (England), Cambridge (Mass.) and Cambridge (Mars).

Answer (score 14):

Actually, "I lucked through my exams" is exactly how you would say it, at least according to [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/luck+through), [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/luck%20through) and my own personal experience.

Comment: @No-Name I'd be interested in where, geographically, "luck through" is common.

Comment: I've also heard "lucked out" used the same way.

Comment: Can you show evidence that 'luck through' is used transitively? 'Luck out' isn't.

Comment: Quite right. There is nothing strange about using "luck" as a verb, and it does not need a following prepositional helper. Here's another reference: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/luck

Comment: "_I lucked my way through_"  might be more natural.

Comment: MW actual says "usually used with out, on, onto, or into".

Answer (score 7):

I **got lucky with** my exams (I see this was also noted by @mjf in comments above). (From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20lucky), "to have good luck : to succeed because of good luck" (note the close association with sex, as noted in previous comments: "get lucky" also means "to succeed in finding or getting someone to agree to have sex with one" — although I don't think there's any danger of confusion/misinterpretation in this context).

(As a phrasal verb, this answer arguably this does not satisfy the [single-word-request] tag, but the original example, "lucked through", is *also* a phrasal verb ... as are many of the other answers here ... "lucked up", "lucked out", not to mention "won the lottery". Of the current answers, only "fluked" [which is not common in my experience in AmE!] is a single word ...)

Answer (score 1):

"I really won the lottery when I got through those exams." [1]

[1] Note: in this case, "really" is just used for emphasis, and not actually meaning that a person really did win a lottery.

"I pulled off a miracle when I got through those exams."

"I was fortunate through those exams."

If you were just a lucky guesser, "I guessed my way through those exams."

There is also the concept of verbing a noun.  (Interestingly, the word "verb" refers to a type of word, which is a noun, so the word "verb" is a noun, so the phrase "verbing a noun" is an example of verbing a noun.)  If you can think of any familiar examples, whether historical and global or even recent and local, of a lucky person or event, you could use a word that refers to a lucky person or event.  For example, "I Stevened my way through those exams last week" might not be readily understood in general, but if the conversation was just discussing how Steven spectacularly pulled off a streak of luck in four different ways over the past few days, then associating Steven's name with the word "luck" could be understood to anyone familiar with the context.

Comment: Note that only the 'single word request' tag has been chosen. And verbing nouns is not totally productive; excessive use should be wastebasketed.